# JsonResult ASP.NET Entity Framework Core Error

Tags: json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, jsonresult

I am creating an app through ASP.Net Core 1.0 and EF Core. I have my models and my view model mapped out with AutoaMapper.

When I create a controller and call it, I get this error:

> Error Number:208,State:1,Class:16
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
>   CRAMSCore1.Models.CramsRepository:Error: Error getting complaints
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor:Information: Executing JsonResult, writing value.

When I check my Sql Profiler on SSMS, I do see that it is querying the database with:

> SQL:BatchCompleted SELECT [c].[COMP_ID], [c].[AddrCity], [c].[AddrState], [c].[AddrZip], [c].[Address], [c].[CRORoute_DT]
>   FROM [Complaints] AS [c]    Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider

My Repository looks very simple:

```
public IEnumerable<COMPLAINT> getAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.Complaints
                .ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error getting complaints", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My controller looks like:

```
[HttpGet("")]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var complaints = _repository.getAll();
        var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ComplaintViewModel>>(complaints);
        return Json(complaints);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does running that SQL manually give you?  The error doesn't appear to have anything to do with your JSONResult but more to do with the retrieval of data from SQL via the EF.

I'm also guessing your return should be

```
return Json(results);
```

Comment: It appears my DBcontext isn't working like it was when it was EF7. I'll have to debug that...